# Creating class instance in the function of other class in typescript

Tags: function, class, instance, typescript

I want to debug my project and I find small problem with creating  instance of class. I try to describe it on simple example.

```
//this is saved in file Engine.ts
module Car {
    export class Engine {
        name: string;

        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
         }

         getName(): string{
            return this.name;
        }
    }
}
```

This class describes simple engine with his name. Now I want to create Engine in some vehicle:

```
///<reference path="Engine.ts"/>
//this is saved in file app.ts
module Car {
    export class Vehicle {
        name: string;
        constructor(name: string) {
            this.name = name;
        }
        buildCar() : string {
            var engine = new Engine("Volkswagen 1.9TDI");
            return "Name of the vehicle is " + this.name + " and has engine " + engine.getName();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    var car = new Car.Vehicle("Skoda Rapid");
    alert(car.buildCar);
}
```

The problem is with creating instance of class Engine. The browser console returns error that Car.Engine is not a constructor. How can I fix this problem? I have more difficult project and this describes only main principle of problem. In my project I must create instance of some class in  function of other class.

Comment: That line is already inside the Car module, so it doesn't need to be qualified

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It sounds like you've compiled to engine.js and app.js, but have not actually loaded engine.js through a `script` tag like you have for app.js.

Comment: I don't think that is the correct solution... We can't load many files in the HTMl file... I am using Systemjs to load the files.... And coming this error it is working just fine for me in ES5 but not in ES6....

Answer (score 1):

As well as sometimes being related to not including the script at runtime, [as Ryan answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526090/75525) (definitely the case for this specific question), this can also be caused by the ordering of classes within a file.

Moving the class mentioned in the error to a position before it is used will solve the problem if this is the problem you have.

Answer (score 0):

Compile app.ts with the --out compiler flag.  This will include the code for engine.ts in the generated file.